# Visual Studio 2022 Intellisense not working on VB to C# Project Conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am working on converting an enterprise winforms application from vb.net to c#. I have the Infrastructure and Core Projects converted to c#, but the Winform UI project in VB does not provide intellisense on the C# compiled projects..

I can run the project and things are working fine, just need to figure out the intellisense issue..

Keep in mind I have never worked on a multiple programming language solution like this before..

I have tried to find resources on this, but no luck. If anyone has a recommendation please let me know..

Thanks....

Comment: Clean/Rebuild/Close VS and open again/rebuild.... then see again

Comment: I think the IntelliSense database is stored in the .vs folder where the solution is located, you could also try deleting that folder to force Visual Studio to rebuild it.

Comment: Trying both recommendations from TS and Craig. Stay tuned !

Comment: Solution from Craig Solved the issue..  Browsed to solution location deleted the .vs folder and rebuilt the solution. Now Intellisense is working in both the VB and C# projects..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wanted to post the answer provided to this question, provided by Craig above, so anyone that comes across it will find the solution easily.

So it turns out that the solution intellisense DB was corrupted.
I closed visual studio, located the solution folder and deleted the .vs folder
re-opened Visual Studio 2022, then cleaned the solution and rebuilt..

Intellisense is now working in both VB and C# projects..

Thanks Craig, saved me a ton of time..